# A/B Testing - Why Variant A mail is being sent to all the recipients as default?

Tags: exm, content-testing

I'm Performing A/B Testing.Having 2 variant mails and 10 recipients. I specified the size of test as **40%**. So the mail was sent to **4** recipients. In that **4** recipients, person who received **variant B** mail, have opened it. So based on **highest open rate** the rest 6 recipients must receive **Variant B** mail. But the issue is, rest of the members are getting **Variant A** mail only. Whenever i perform A/B testing i'm getting **Variant A** mail only. Can anyone explain me WHY???

[image]